# Запятые в предложении с однородными сказуемыми

Tags: сказуемые, однородные-члены

Это есть и в нынешние времена(,) и было(,) и будет.

Правильно ли здесь расставлены запятые (три однородных сказуемых)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Три однородных сказуемых, соединенных повторяющимся союзом "и". По правилам необходимо ставить запятые перед каждым союзом, соединяющим однородные члены предложения: Это есть и в нынешние времена, и было, и будет. Ср.: Листья в поле пожелтели, и кружатся, и летят, и устилаю землю золотым ковром.